# allow a user to choose a location to save file on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fileserver

so when the user uploads a file, I need to allow him/her to be able to choose a location on a remote file-server. Are there any file choosers that allow a user to browse a file-server? This would be through an asp.net mvc-3 website if it makes a difference. (The file server is just a remote hard drive).

I need a hint in the right direction. What should I be looking for/at?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find anything out of the box that does that.  Basically, you will need to create a Treeview file browser menu (for mvc client-side jquery control is preferable, [jquery-file-tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/))  functionality which represents the folder structure where a user can save.  Then, upon choosing the right folder that information is pushed along with the uploaded file, and mvc controller can handles the logic to save in appropriate folder.
Note, you will need read/write access on the server by the application pool account to preserve the file.

Comment: I was hoping for another answer - it looks like a bit of work. I guess I'll scrape the directory and ajax it to a tree. Thanks.